# Angular appends parent attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, hierarchy

I have hierarchical data like this:

```
[  
    {  
        "children":[  
            {  
                "children":[...],
                [...]
            },
            {  
                "children":[...],
                [...]
            },
        ],
        [...]
    }
]
```

I want to build tree-like grid by flattening that data. I am using following directives:

```
app.directive('tree', function (hierarchyService, logger, $timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>' +
            '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">' +
            '    <thead>' +
            '        <tr>' +
            '            <th class="col-md-6">Account name</th>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '        </thead>' +
            '        <tbody><tr collection data="data" /></tbody>' +
            '    </table>' +
            '</div>'
    };
});

app.directive('collection', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            depth: '@'
        },
        template: '<member ng-repeat="member in data" member="member" depth="{{depth}}" />',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.depth = parseInt(scope.depth || 0);
        }
    }
});

app.directive('member', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            depth: '@',
            member: '='
        },
        template: '<tr ng-class="{selected: member.selected}">' +
            '<td>' +
            '   <span ng-show="depth > 0" style="width: {{depth * 16}}px; display: inline-block;"></span> {{member.name}}' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.depth = parseInt(scope.depth || 0);

            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children) && scope.member.children.length > 0) {
                var el = angular.element('<tr collection data="member.children" depth="{{newDepth}}" />');
                scope.depth = parseInt(scope.depth || 0);
                scope.newDepth = scope.depth + 1;
                $compile(el)(scope);

                // Flatten hierarchy, by appending el to parent
                element.parent().append(el);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that, in collection added from `link` method, `depth` from parent scope is appended to `newDepth`. As a result `depth` for level 3 nodes has value `depth="3 2 1 "`.

How to disable inheriting of `depth`?

I have also noticed, that when I change `replace` to false in `collection` and `member` directives, depth works as intended, but then HTML is invalid.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker or fiddle for your case?

Comment: @SpartakLalaj Here you are: https://plnkr.co/edit/CE2z5WeU41H4qJQQ73B7?p=preview

Comment: I removed depth attribute and declared it with equal sign in collection and seems that the numbers are correct. Try and see if that is the correct result!

Comment: The modified plunker is this: https://plnkr.co/edit/w794aydNu8rkeYj8dEWl?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that using the same scope for child nodes, causes that weird concatenation. Cure to that is pretty simple, as it turned out - new child scope is required for each child. Link function will look like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children) && scope.member.children.length > 0) {
        // Create isolated child scope, pass `scope` as parent
        var childScope = scope.$new(true, scope);
        childScope.depth = parseInt(scope.depth || 0) + 1;
        childScope.member = scope.member;

        var el = angular.element('<tr collection data="member.children" depth="{{depth}}" />');

        // use child scope
        $compile(el)(childScope);

        // Flatten hierarchy, by appending el to parent
        element.after(el);
    }
}
```

Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/xhJwfV?p=preview

I have also found somewhere else on SO and in API, that `replace` is deprecated, so actually it should't be used. So without replace it can look like this:

```
app.directive('tree', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>' +
            '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">' +
            '    <thead>' +
            '        <tr>' +
            '            <th class="col-md-6">Account name</th>' +
            '            <th class="col-md-1">Depth</th>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '        </thead>' +
            '        <tbody row data="data"></tbody>' +
            '    </table>' +
            '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.data = [
              { 
                name: 'Root',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Level 1',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'Level 2',
                        children: [
                          {name: "Level 3"},
                          {name: "Level 3 -1"}
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Level 1-1"
                  }
                ]
              }
          ];
        }
    };
});

app.directive('row', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            data:  '=',
            depth: '@'
        },
        template: '<tr cells ng-repeat="member in data" member="member" />',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.depth = parseInt(scope.depth || 0);
        }
    }
});

app.directive('cells', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            data:  '=',
            depth:  '@',
            member: '='
        },
        template: //'<tr ng-class="{selected: member.selected}">' +
            '<td>' +
            '   <span ng-show="depth > 0" style="width: {{depth * 16}}px; display: inline-block;"></span> {{member.name}}' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>{{depth}}</td>',
            //'</tr>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.member && angular.isArray(scope.member.children) && scope.member.children.length > 0) {
                var childScope = scope.$new(true);
                childScope.depth = parseInt(scope.depth || 0) + 1;
                childScope.data = scope.member.children;

                var el = angular.element('<tr cells ng-repeat="member in data" member="member" depth="{{depth}}" />');

                $compile(el)(childScope);

                // Flatten hierarchy, by appending el to parent
                element.after(el);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/j3YcuQ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes much simpler solutions are better. It is better to flatten tree like structures in service and then iterate over new structure using ng-repeat. https://plnkr.co/edit/CiFGZYi6NdH8ZFDiAyPz?p=preview

Much simpler code. There is no need for all those directives that make it hard to understand. Also you should not use replace with directives as it is [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

To set style dynamically you should use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('treeFlatting', function () {
  function flattenTree(tree, depth) {
    depth = depth || 0;

    return tree.reduce(function (rows, node) {
      var row = {
        name: node.name,
        depth: depth,
      };
      var childrenRows = angular.isArray(node.children) ? 
        flattenTree(node.children, depth + 1) : [];

      return rows.concat(row, childrenRows);
    }, []);
  }

  return flattenTree;
});

app.directive('tree', function (treeFlatting) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>' +
            '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">' +
            '    <thead>' +
            '        <tr>' +
            '            <th class="col-md-6">Account name</th>' +
            '            <th class="col-md-1">Depth</th>' +
            '        </tr>' +
            '        </thead>' +
            '        <tbody>'+
            '          <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">'+
            '             <td ng-style="{\'padding-left\': (16 * row.depth) + \'px\'}">{{row.name}}</td>'+
            '             <td>{{row.depth}}</td>'+
            '          </tr>'+
            '        </tbody>' +
            '    </table>' +
            '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.data = [
              { 
                name: 'Root',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Level 1',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'Level 2'
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
          ];

          scope.rows = treeFlatting(scope.data).filter(function (row) {
            return row.depth > 0;
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I also can use dedicated tree component, but it's not a point. This behavior is at least weird in my opinion, and I would like to now if it's intended (and can be disabled somehow) or if it's a bug. The weirdest thing is that when I switch replace flag to false, then it works fine (but then markup is messed).

Comment: I haven't look that close at it, but I bet that issue is with using '@' and string concatenation. btw. Why did you do that in such a strange way?

Comment: I'm just playing with angular, and that behavior is not what I expected. Since I ran into that problem I would like to know solution.